# Why would the compiler link to the wrong method when MS Release library is used?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, linker

Program links to the wrong method in Release mode.  I have C++ solution with 9 projects being built with VS2019 WIN32. It runs fine in Debug build but when built in Release it fails with an error:
*Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.*
This occurs when returning from a method call in a dll that is not mine.

I made a new configuration that is a copy of the Debug build. It runs just fine.
I then changed the preprocessor definition from _DEBUG to NDEBUG in all 9 projects and rebuilt the solution.  It runs just fine.
I then changed the Runtime Library from 'Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)' to 'Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)' in all 9 projects and rebuilt the solution ( takes the better part of an hour ). This time I get the stack error shown above during runtime.

Tracing the disassembly, I found the /MD version was calling the expected method with 3 pointers as parameters but the method it executed had only one parameter so the cleanup left 8 bytes on the stack, generating the error.
According to the include file, the desired method is a virtual function in a sizable class.  That class has several successful method calls into it during runtime before hitting the erroneous method.
To verify, I changed all 9 Runtime Library back to /MDd, rebuilt, and got a running program.

How does the library version link differently while all the preprocessor defines are the same?

Comment: I would set a blank project to just link that dll and invoke the problematic method to see if the problem replicates. I don't think the linker has anything to do with dll since the linking takes place dynamically on load-time or run-time with `GetProcAddress`

Comment: To clarify. This is a simple method call. No templates, no vtable manipulation, just a class->method(ptr,ptr,ptr). Diving deeper into the include files, the method getting executed is declared as a virtual function directly before the virtual function being called from the main program. Nothing changed but the runtime library. The include files, the dll's library and the dll are all exactly the same. What could make the linker move the call by 4 bytes?

Comment: MatG:  If I go to the expense of replicating this / or not / in a smaller program, what will that tell me?

Comment: If the problem replicates, you have a smaller and simple project to post; if the problem don't replicate, you narrow the causes and can analyze the differences between the two projects. You continue to talk about the linker, but it has nothing to do with DLL libraries: the bindings take place when you run the program.

Answer (score -1):

The solution was to get a Release build of the Dynamic Link Library. Apparently the supplier released a Debug build.
MS must link in extra stuff in Debug making the offsets shift up a pointer in Release mode.